Pasting to multiple cells is not triggered if in a filter view
The following Google Apps Script works fine when viewing the spreadsheet normally:
function notify(edit)
{
  const sheet = edit.source.getActiveSheet()
  const sheetName = edit.source.getActiveSheet().getName()
  const column = edit.range.getColumn()
  const row = edit.range.getRow()
  const rows = edit.range.getNumRows()
  const value = edit.range.getValue()
  
  if (sheetName === 'Bugs' && column === 33 && value === true)
  {
    for(var i = 0; i < rows; i ++)
    {
      webhook(sheet.getRange(row + i, 34).getValue(), sheet.getRange(row + i, 35).getValue())
      Utilities.sleep(2000)
    }
  }
}

function webhook(post, message)
{
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1235813427104976916/XXX?thread_id=${post}`, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, method: 'POST', payload: JSON.stringify({content: message})})
}

It successfully triggers the webhook function several times when I paste TRUE in multiple cells at once.
However, if I enter a filter view, it only triggers once for one cell. Why is that?

This should be asked to Googlers rather than a community of end-users. It might also be something to be posted as an issue in the Google Apps Script Issue tracker.  See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support.

I just think about range list. Your script is set to handle a single range, but you might be pasting to multiple ranges when pasting on a filter view. Check if edit.range.getSheet().getActiveRangeList() returns all the ranges edited by your paste operation. It might be a good idea to include a "minimal complete example": show the sheet structure, describe the filter applie, the pasted values and the resulting sheet.
